# Have two image buttons on the same activity

Tags: android, android-activity

What I want is to open my app and click the image button and that brings me to another activity with a different image button. However when I run it, the two images appear on both activities at the same time. Anyone have any clues?

```
ImageButton imagebtn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebtn2);
        imagebtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                Intent intent = new Intent
                        (Scrape.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

This is my code, the MainActivity is the same code just different names. Below is my manifest.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Scrape"
            android:label="@string/app_name1"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

This is my xml.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imagebtn1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/got" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imagebtn2"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/timetable" />
```

MainActivity*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageButton imagebtn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebtn1);
        imagebtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                Intent intent = new Intent
                        (MainActivity.this, Scrape.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: for the second activity which you want to fire after button click you should remove intent filter tag from manifest. so onstart only one activity will launch

Comment: i removed them from the scrape part but it still closes down, any clue?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is this:

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/imagebtn1"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:src="@drawable/got" />

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/imagebtn2"
android:layout_width="70dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:src="@drawable/timetable" />
```

You have the two image buttons in the same layout file.

If you want to have the two in different activities, then you can create a second layout and place one image button inside it and then keep the first image button in the first layout file.

As noted in the comment above, you want one activity to be the launcher activity in your application.

I hope this helps!

Comment: well it got rid of one of the button but then when i click it it stops the app, any idea what the reason is?

Comment: @DylanB: logcat or the debugger didn't tell you?

Comment: its too big to post, it says the error is on line 33, imagebtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: Did you delete imagebtn2 from your layout...?

Comment: yeah, it was in content_main and then i create a xml called scrape and put it in there

Comment: Do you think that the fact you deleted it might have something to do with the fact that you get an error when you try to reference `imagebtn2`?

Comment: imagebtn2 is in a serperate xml file, as i had to because they overlapped, did you read the answer were talking in?

Comment: And you are sure that you are loading the XML file that contains imagebtn2 in the same activity where you try to reference it, the one that's crashing?

Comment: imagebtn2 is in the scrape xml class, the imagebtn is in the content_main class, the mainactivty is what im launching, its in the edit above

Comment: Just make sure your `scrape.xml` has a button with `ID` that matches with whatever ID you reference in your activity. Also, `setContentView()`in that activity should point to your `scrape.xml`. The same applies to other activity.

Comment: Thanks man , it was the contentView was set wrong , works now, cheers again